# Paso por referencia en funciones

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un proyecto y necesito pasar por la cabecera de la función un arraylist y un entero. La funcion puede ser void o devolver una de las dos cosas.

El caso es que no sé como hacerlo en java ya que acabo de conocerlo, en C++ por ejemplo trabajando con las referencias y punteros estaría.

Por ejemplo en c++ haria:

```
Int función(int[] *vector, Int tam);
```

Sería trabajar con punteros y al llamar la función usar & (la referencia) para que los cambios realizados al vector, se queden al salir de la función y no se haga en una copia de ese vector.

Ahora quiero hacer lo mismo con java.

```
FuncionRellenaVector(arraylis vector, Int tam) { \for qué rellena el vector de num aleatorios }

Arraylist vector=New arraylis() ;

FunciónRellenaVector(vector, 20);
```

Mi sorpresa es que cuando sale de la función el vector no se ha modificado. Este es mi problema Gracias y disculpen la torpeza

**Vista mi poca capacidad para expresar el problema, voy a plantear otra cuestión.
Como hacer que una función devuelva dos valores, por ejemplo enteros**

Comment: Agrega el codigo que llevas de tu problema hasta el momento para que aquellos que esten dispuesto a ayudar tengan una referencia de tu problema.

Comment: A pesar del poco código proporcionado creo que he entendido el problema que tienes, puedes ver mi respuesta.

Comment: Podría meter todo el archivo el archivo sobre el que estoy trabajando pero es una función de metaheurística y veia mas sencillo de enternder este ejemplo, además de que esta extraido del archivo

Comment: @DavidValdivia Yo te di una posible solución, mira mi respuesta. Con respecto a lo otro, una función no puede retornar dos valores, solo puede devolver un valor.

Answer (score 1):

> Tengo entendido que Java hace el pasaje de parámetros por valor y no por referencia. Un ejemplo de esto es:

```
int entero = 0;
ref(entero);
System.out.println(entero);//resulta 0


public void ref(int ent){
ent=5;
}
```

> Esto es porque: entero = 0 ; ent = entero; ent = 5; no se modifica nunca entero. Pero si de objetos se trata pasa algo distinto.

```
ArrayList<Integer> vector;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
vector = new ArrayList<Integer>();
vector.add(3);
```

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void metodo(ArrayList<Integer> parametro){
parametro.add(5);
parametro.add(6);
```

}

> Entonces vector = 3 ; parametro = vector pero en este caso al poner igual lo que hacemos es apuntar a donde apunta vector.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Una vez que termina de ejecutarse el método, las variables locales se eliminan para que se las lleve el recolector de basura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Aplicado a tu algoritmo seria, por ejemplo si los haces en el main.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
 ArrayList<Integer> vector = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 funcionModificaVector(vector,20);
 System.out.println(vector.get(0));//muestra 20
}
public static void funcionModificaVector(ArrayList<Integer>vector, int tam) 
{ 
  vector.add(tam);
}
```

Comment: Hola, esto no responde a la pregunta, ¿porque que el vector no se ha modificado?, ayúdanos a responder preguntas basadas en [ask], saludos.

Comment: El titulo es "paso por referencia en funciones", mi respuesta es correcta; si no le funciona es que esta haciendo algo mal y para eso como aconsejan nuestros queridos colegas necesitamos ver el código que implemento

Comment: Exacto Sergio,de hecho muchas gracias por tu contribución, solo recuerda que es importante preguntar como comentario a la persona que pregunta que aclare  su pregunta agregando detalles, saludos!

Comment: Has comentado que "Esto es porque: entero = 0 ; ent = entero; ent = 5; no se modifica nunca entero. Pero si de objetos se trata pasa algo distinto." Como puede hacer que una función me devuelva dos enteros.

Comment: No se puede, tenes que por ejemplo usar un arreglo con dos enteros.

Answer (score 1):

> > Mi sorpresa es que cuando sale de la función el vector no se ha modificado.

Miremos el siguiente código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class VectorX
{
    public static void rellenar(ArrayList v, int tam)
    {
        //System.out.println(v);
        v = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        v.add(tam);

    }
}

public class Program
{

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        ArrayList a = null;
        VectorX.rellenar(a, 10);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

A simple vista, pensaríamos que el resultado en pantalla es `10`, pero en realidad da un `null`.

**¿Por qué dio un null?**

La respuesta es sencilla, en Java no es posible pasar la dirección de memoria de un argumento.

Esto quiere decir, que el parámetro `v` recibe el contenido de lo que apunte `a` (en este caso `null`).

Cuando el método `rellenar` se llame y ejecute esta línea:

```
v = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Esa sentencia no estaría modificando el contenido del puntero implícito `a` (porqué en Java no existe el concepto de pasar por referencia) sino, le estaría asignando un nuevo objeto al parámetro `v`. Luego que la función termine de ejecutarse, la referencia de ese objeto se pierde y por esa razón, la variable `a` se queda con `null`.

**Una de las soluciones sería:** Eliminar la instancia que se tiene en el método `rellenar`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class VectorX
{
    public static void rellenar(ArrayList v, int tam)
    {
        v.add(tam);

    }
}

public class Program
{

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a.add(9);
        VectorX.rellenar(a, 10);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Esto daría como resultado `9 y 10`.

**¿Por qué dio 9 y 10?**

Esto se debe, porqué el parámetro `v` está recibiendo el contenido de lo que apunte `a`, que básicamente es la dirección base del objeto instanciado. Entonces, cuando se ejecute esta línea:

```
v.add(tam);
```

Estaríamos añadiendo el objeto en la misma lista (la que apunte `a`).

Sin embargo, me di cuenta, que quieres crear el objeto adentro de la clase y no en cualquier lugar. Lo que puedes hacer es crear un atributo en la misma clase donde esté ese método.

Por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class VectorX
{
    private static ArrayList a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static ArrayList getV()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public static void rellenar(ArrayList v, int tam)
    {
        v.add(tam);
    }
}

public class Program
{

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        VectorX.rellenar(VectorX.getV(), 9);
        VectorX.rellenar(VectorX.getV(), 10);
        System.out.println(VectorX.getV());
    }
}
```

Básicamente lo que hace el código, es crear el objeto en la clase `VectorX` y para poder tener acceso al atributo `a`, se lo hace con el `getV()`.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías mostrar una parte de tu código, pero a ver si esto aclara tu duda:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class PruebaFuncion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       List<Integer> lista =new ArrayList<>();
       lista.add(5);
       lista.add(6);


        //Mostramos la lista
       System.out.println(lista);
       //ejecutamos función
       funcion(lista,10);
       System.out.println("==== lista modificada ====");
        //volvemos a mostrar
       System.out.println(lista);
    }
//    el metodo lo declaré estático para no tener que crear un objeto
    public static void funcion(List<Integer> listaParametro, int valor){
        listaParametro.add(valor);
    }
}
```

Conclusión: **no** se creó una `copia de la lista`, sino que la `lista` se modificó

Comment: Hola, la duda es ¿porque que el vector no se ha modificado?, ayúdanos a responder preguntas basadas en [ask], saludos.

Comment: no no, la duda es: ..para que los cambios realizados al vector, se queden al salir de la función y no se haga en una copia de ese vector. De todas formas lo hice con `array` y pide con `ArrayList`, ya lo edito..